# SVG mime type to Firebase application

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Google's Firebase to host my node application. I have an SVG file which is producing an error in the console:

> "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection."

I have tried adding a header to the firebase.json file

```
   "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(svg)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "svg+xml"
          }
        ]
      } 
    ]
```

However the svg file is still being loaded as a text/html. How can I make the webserver respect the firebase.json content type for svg files?